# How can I upload save games to the steam cloud on unreal engine?

Tags: steam, unreal-engine5, savechanges

Good day,
I am making a game and am going to have save games as you go through the game as to save the players  progress. Later on I will try and launch the game on steam but i was wondering how i would upload the save games to the steam cloud so players can access thier data on any device. How would I do this.

I have looked it up and there is infomation on how to connect to steam works but not on this subject.